# How to use the MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL setting with mysql_connect() in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CA certificate of the mysql database I am trying to connect to (it's on Amazon rds). I can't find a good example of how to connect to the mysql database using php's mysql_connect() function, and using that ca certificate (stored at /home/username/mysql_ca_cert.pem) to connect.

Could anyone help me with a simple example?

Comment: I'd advise against using the mysql_* functions, use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: @GordonM, what is wrong with mysql_* functions ?

Comment: They're badly outdated, they have not been updated to take advantage of features offered by mysql 5, and they are deprecated in all but name.

Comment: @GordonM, thanks for the advice. unfortunately, i have some legacy code using mysql_connect which I have to maintain, so I am still interested in this question if anyone has an answer.

Comment: PDO is absolutely the way. It has prepared statements. Just for that PDO should become the standard and mysql_/mysql_ functions be deprecated.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli, if only i could use PDO..... unfortunately, i can't in this scenario

Comment: Maybe if you have to maintain this codebase, you should consider switching to mysqli ? I found a [script for this](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Converting_to_MySQLi). 

Just saying it because neither you nor me nor 4+ people found a clear option to select a cert to connect via mysql legacy extension. 

I guess you can also use a ssl tunnel to connect. see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418206/using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql-from-php#2418242)

Answer (score 0):

This will connect using the servers ssl cert the 2048 is the key

```
$link=mysql_connect(host, user, password,true,2048);
```

Comment: @Mark Allen, how do i connect this with my ssl cert file located at  /home/username/mysql_ca_cert.pem?

Comment: Take a look at the last message. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778977/encrypting-mysql-traffic-in-scripts

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect() is depreciated and highly hackable.
To use it is the ultimate in foolish

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=ip;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT=>'/etc/mysql/ssl/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    =>'/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem'
    )
);
$statement = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

```
$db = mysqlii_init(); 
$db->ssl_set('server-key.pem','server-cert.pem', 'cacert.pem', NULL, NULL); 
$db->real_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
```

and afterwards of course

```
$db->close();
```

hope that helps :)

Answer (score -2):

You probably could try mysqli::ssl_set

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

Comment: I need to use the mysql_connect() function. It's legacy code.